# Deleting nested child-elements

Tags: jquery

I got three nested "box"-container: box_1, box_2 and box_3.
Now I want to detroy the html-construct of such a box by clicking on ".box_delete". Therefore I wrote the small JQuery-Script.

**HTML:**

```
<section class="box_1">
    <div class="box_delete"></div>
    <header class="trigger"><h2 contenteditable="true">TITLE</h2></header>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="editable">
            <p>Level1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box_2">
            <div class="box_delete"></div>
            <div class="box_rand"></div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="editable">
                    <p>Level2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="box_3">
                    <div class="box_delete"></div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="editable">
                            <p>Level3-1</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box_3">
                    <div class="box_delete"></div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="editable">
                            <p>Level3-2</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.box_delete').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).blur();
    var box = $(this).parent().closest("[class*='box_']");
    var aBlocks = $(box).find('.editable').html();
    $(aBlocks).replaceAll(box);
});
```

This is working for destroying one level by another.

But if box_delete of "box_2" is being clicked, both boxes (box_3 and box_2) should be deleted. So in this case the result should be:

```
<section class="box_1">
    <div class="box_delete"></div>
    <header class="trigger"><h2 contenteditable="true">TITLE</h2></header>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="editable">
            <p>Level1</p>
        </div>
        <p>Level2</p>
        <p>Level3-1</p>
        <p>Level3-2</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

By clicking on box_delete of the first level box, all children boxes should also beeing destroyed. Then the content would be just:

```
TITLE
<p>Level1</p>
<p>Level2</p>
<p>Level3-1</p>
<p>Level3-2</p>
```

There can be multiple box_3-elements in one box_2-element and multiple box_2-elements in a box_1 element. In this case always ALL children-box-level should be destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.box_delete').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).blur();
    var box = $(this).parent().closest("[class*='box_']");
    var new = '';
    $(".editable", box).each(function(){ new = new+$(this).html(); });
    $(new).replaceAll(box);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
        $('.box_delete').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).blur();
            var box = $(this).parent().closest("[class*='box_']");
            $(".editable p", box).replaceAll(box);
        });
```

Comment: It doesn't work if I delete first the both box_3-elements and then the box_2 element. The title gets lost if you are deleting the first box... It would also be great if the html-content of the boxes would remain - undependent if there are just p-elements or something else (i.e. ul, li)